# White borders around

Tags: html, css

I tried so many times to fit my 5 pictures to my whole page. I don't want any borders (white,black,nothing...) on the sides...

////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////

There is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <style>
 body, html {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
 .column {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px 0px 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 .column:last-child {
     padding-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .column::after {
     content: '';
     clear: both;
     display: block;
 }
 .column div {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     width: 384px;
     height: 1080px;
 }
 .column div:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
 }
 figure {
     width: 384px;
     height: 1080px;
     background: #fff;
 }
 figure:hover+span {
     bottom: -36px;
     opacity: 1;
 }
 .hover figure img {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
     filter: grayscale(100%);
     -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
     transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 }
 .hover figure:hover img {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
     filter: grayscale(0);
 }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="hover column">
 <div>
   <figure><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCIMApU.jpg" /></figure>
 </div>
 <div>
   <figure><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCIMApU.jpg" /></figure>
 </div>
 <div>
   <figure><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCIMApU.jpg" /></figure>
 </div>
  <div>
   <figure><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCIMApU.jpg" /></figure>
 </div> 
 <div>
   <figure><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCIMApU.jpg" /></figure>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And, is it possible to put a logo in the center of the page?
Thanks in advance !

#html #css #web

Comment: It is unclear if the logo shall be in the background or in the foreground. - Have a look at  the border, marging, and padding properties of your HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

May you add more information to your question(s)? If I understand correctly, you want to remove the whitespace in between images and around them. You should add a Meyers reset to remove any pre-styling the browser applies.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

This should remove the whitespace issue you're experiencing. If you're trying to cover the entire web page with this image, the best route may be to add it as a background image.

```css
.div1 {
    height: 1080px;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/bCIMApU.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
 <div class="div1">
        
 </div>
 <div class="div1">
        
 </div>
 <div class="div1">
        
 </div>
 <div class="div1">
        
 </div>
```

As for the logo, do you want it to be in the center at all times? (During scroll, etc.)

Comment: First of all, thanks for trying to help me. I didn't explain it correctly, my bad.

I've added the same link, 5 times, but it's a different image. My projet is to make a webpage with differents categories at the begginning. So the people will have to select the good category to go to a specific page. 

[link](https://i.imgur.com/EB4iSaQ.png) This is what I want to do exactly.